# ggplot time series plot long data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a pivot long data set (see below) and I'm totally stumped on doing a time series plot of the result but only for ONE subject and ONE part at a time????. Code below will reproduce some sample data date format yyyy-mm-dd. Any guidance or links to help will be greatly appreciated.

```
df = data.frame(date = c('1-8-2011', '1-9-2011', '1-10-2011', '1-11-2011', '1-8-2011', '1-9-2011', '1-10-2011', '1-11-2011', '1-8-2011', '1-9-2011', '1-10-2011', '1-11-2011', '1-8-2011', '1-9-2011', '1-10-2011', '1-11-2011'),
            subject = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
            part = c('arm', 'arm', 'arm', 'arm', 'leg', 'leg', 'leg', 'leg', 'arm', 'arm', 'arm', 'arm', 'leg', 'leg', 'leg', 'leg'),
            result = c(34, 35, 32, 37, 55, 56, 37, 37, 38, 40, 32, 37, 45, 45, 48, 50))

df$date = as.Date(df$date, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `facet_grid` using the formula `subject~part` or vice versa. The "outcome" in the model will be the rows and the "predictor" will be the columns.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(date, result)) +
  facet_grid(subject ~ part)
```

[image]

You can use the dplyr package's filter function to select the subject and part that you want. For subject a's arm, the following code will produce a plot.

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(filter(df, subject=="a" & part=="arm")) +
  geom_line(aes(date, result))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm actually only after one plot at time, not a grid...the data sets has > 100 subjects and many more parts.

Comment: Gotcha, just use `filter` to choose the rows corresponding to the subject & body part and then use ggplot as usual.